# How to filter ng-Table with multiple values in an array.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, ngtable, selectize.js

I'm currently implementing angular-selectize.js (https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize) to add a search box that will take in multiple values and filter all cells in ng-Table base on these values without specifying which columns to filter. Similar to results from creating a search box with input and do `filter:search` on `ng-repeat` but filtering with multiple values instead.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/701op5FQ0PRJ5FOlF5Mq?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created a custom filter and it worked. 
Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/701op5FQ0PRJ5FOlF5Mq?p=preview

```
  .filter('filterSelectize', function($filter){
    return function(cars, multiArray) {
      if(multiArray.length >= 1){
        var filteredCars = cars;
        for(i=0; i < multiArray.length; i++){
          var filteredCars = $filter('filter')(filteredCars, multiArray[i]);
        }
        return filteredCars;
      }
      else {
        return cars;
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also go the "official" ngTable way with the filter key $:

```
function applyGlobalSearch(){
      var term = self.globalSearchTerm;
      if (self.isInvertedSearch){
        term = "!" + term;
      }
      self.tableParams.filter({ $: term });
    }
```

https://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/doEbJW?editors=1010